# When is a character actually frozen?

Tags: overwatch

Mei is a character who freezes things. It's what she does. Freezing enemy players is an effective way to immobilize them and land a perfect headshot (killing many of the lower health characters). Typically, the way an encounter works is that you'll spray them with your primary fire, and then headshot them with your alternate fire once they're frozen.

This doesn't leave you with a lot of time, though. Once a character his the freezing point, there's an animation of their body being covered in ice. When exactly are they considered frozen (i.e. I don't need to keep spraying them), so I know to begin headshot protocol?

Answer (score 13):

The exact timing for being fully frozen is after 2 seconds of being under primary fire from Mei, during which the character will get progressively slower in both movement and turning speed, and a distinctive "freeze crack" sound will play the moment the player fully loses control over they character. Listen for the sound cue or watch when the character's movement completely stops.